# Сравнение двух таблиц? (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

В результате ошибки накосячил немного при объединении базы людей.
В некоторых записях (много) полное ФИО сократилось до короткого, например "Иванов Иван Иванович" до "Иванов И.И."

В итоге сейчас есть две таблицы (старая бекап) и новая объединенная (где есть ошибки)

Как мне запросом сверить записи по ID в двух таблицах и если в таблице bekap поле fullname имеет большее кол-во символов чем запись с этим же ID в таблице NEW
то записать даннные полей
fullname, firstname и middlename из таблицы bekap в таблицу NEW ?

Comment: Лучше сравнивать не длину - а именно строго проверить записи, что применив формулу сокращения к полю таблицы бекапа получаем значение, совпадающее с текущей записью.

Comment: Строгое соотвествие не подойдет, так как при объединении (где я накосячил) как раз таки многие ФИО должны были обновиться до полного варианта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE bekap t1, NEW t2
SET t1.fullname = CONCAT(t2.fullname, ' ', t2.firstname, ' ', t2.middlename)
WHERE LENGTH(t1.fullname) > LENGTH(t2.fullname) /* + 4 */
  AND t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: спасибо, у вас была небольшая ошибка - SET t2.fullname = t1.fullname, t2.firstname = t1.firstname, t2.middlename = t1.middlename

Comment: *у вас была небольшая ошибка* Это не ошибка. Просто кто-то "забыл" показать DDL и пример наполнения.